# add custom class to wordpress nav menu item based on specific condition

Tags: wordpress, class, menu, conditional-statements

I want to add current-menu-item class to the li if it is a single page.
I am trying to do this by using wp_nav_menu_objects hook with a custom function but don't know how to get the particular menu item and set a condition to assign the class to it. 
Here is the code.

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects' , 'my_menu_class');
function my_menu_class($menu) {

    //if it is a single post page of a particular post type (in this case 'property')
    if( is_single() && is_post_type_archive( 'property' ) ) {

    //get all the menu items
    foreach($menu as $key => $item) {

        // check if the menu item is "Commercial Property"
        if($item == "Commercial Property") {  

            //assign the class to that menu item
            $menu[$key]->classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
        }
    }
}   


return $menu;        
}
```

This code is just to represent the logic. Please suggest if what I need can be achieved with this method or there is a better approach to it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my WP theme, I wanted to remove all wordpess menu classes, add my own and on specific condition ( for example if the menu has an active class ) to add another class. Here s my code

```
function add_custom_classes($classes){

    $newClasses[] = "navigation__item";

    if( in_array('current_page_item', $classes) ){
        array_push($newClasses, "navigation__item-active");
    }

    return $newClasses;
}

add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'add_custom_classes', 100, 1);
add_filter('nav_menu_item_id', 'add_custom_classes', 100, 1);
add_filter('page_css_class', 'add_custom_classes', 100, 1);
```

You can add your own conditions

Answer (score 0):

`is_single` is actually looking for a single post. You need `is_page`

Comment: it is the single post page on which I need to add the class to the menu

Comment: Ok, sorry. So it look like you are trying to add the class to a single menu item? Why dont you go to menu and at the top click screen options and make sure css classes is checked. Then you can add any class to a specific list item.

Comment: That will add the class to the menu item on every page where it appears, but I want to add the class only when it is a single post page.

Comment: Are you trying to target it only when on a single page? If you are you can use css to target it `.single .current-menu-item { color: black; }` this CSS will only kick in on singe posts.

Comment: There is no current menu item on the single page as it is coming from an archive page, the wordpress nav menu doesn't know which menu item the current single post belongs to, as the nav menu is created by using pages. If there was a current-menu-item class it would have automatically applied the styles I need.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress already provides the class **if it is a single page**

`current-post-ancestor`

on any post detail page you can inspect the menu you will find that class so in other way  you can utilize `current-post-ancestor` class for what you need to do

Hope it makes sense

Comment: Yes I know about that class and I am using it for the subNav But that will only work for the post or page which is coming directly from  its parent post or page but in this case the menu item is a "page" and   it has not relation to the currently displaying post on the single page.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it using the HTTP_REFERER to set conditions in the same function.
Don't feel it is the best way to achieve this but it sorts me out.

Here is the code if anyone else needs a reference.

```
function nav_menu_class($menu) {

    //To dynamically get the directory path from the URL irrespective of the local or web server.
$ref    = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; // prev page url.
$split_ref  = pathinfo($ref); // splitting the url to seperate the directory (http://dev.calyxagency.com/horizoncapital/site-new/) from the file path.
$dir_path  .= $split_ref[ "dirname" ]; // extracting the host + directory from the full path
$class      = 'current-menu-item'; // class to be assigned.

foreach($menu as $key => $item) {
    if( $menu[$key]-> ID == 101 ) { // check if the menu item matches this ID
        if( $ref == $dir_path.'/properties-to-let/' || $ref == $dir_path.'/properties-for-sale/' || $ref == $dir_path.'/commercial-property/' ) {
            $menu[$key]->classes[] = $class;
        }
    } elseif( $menu[$key]-> ID == 15 ) { // check if the menu item matches this ID
        if( $ref == $dir_path.'/business-for-sale/' ) { // check if the single page has come from this page for assigning current class to only this menu item 
            $menu[$key]->classes[] = $class;
        }
    } elseif( $menu[$key]-> ID == 18 ) { // check if the menu item matches this ID
        if( $ref == $dir_path.'/news/' ) { // check if the single page has come from this page for assigning current class to only this menu item 
            $menu[$key]->classes[] = $class;
        }
    }
} 
return $menu;   
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects' , 'nav_menu_class');
```